# cakephp 3 contain same model twice with different conditions without association

Tags: cakephp, model-associations, cakephp-3.4

I have three tables `ServerScans`, `QueuedJobs`, `ReportMalware`

`ReportMalware` has a column `type` which contain values like `mail`, `abc`.

I am querying ServerScans as

```
$scan = $this->ServerScans->get($id, [
  'contain' => [
     'QueuedJobs',
     'QueuedJobs.ReportMalware',
  ],
]);
```

and in view separating malware report in two groups using for loop as

```
<h2>Mail report</h2>
<?php foreach($scan->queued_jobs->report_malware as $m): ?>
   <?php if ($m->type == 'mail'): ?>
       <?= $m->comment ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>

<h2>Abc report</h2>
<?php foreach($scan->queued_jobs->report_malware as $m): ?>
   <?php if ($m->type == 'abc'): ?>
       <?= $m->comment ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Which will take more time for execution.

What I want is to keep it in contain like

```
$scan = $this->ServerScans->get($id, [
  'contain' => [
     'QueuedJobs',
     'QueuedJobs.ReportMalware.mail',
     'QueuedJobs.ReportMalware.abc',
  ],
]);
```

**Is there a way to achieve this and contain same model twice based on some filter criteria?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do so. See the docs [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#associations-linking-tables-together).

> The same table can be used multiple times to define different types of
>   associations. For example consider a case where you want to separate
>   approved comments and those that have not been moderated yet:

Here is the example taken from the official documentation:

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->hasMany('Comments')
            ->setConditions(['approved' => true]);

        $this->hasMany('UnapprovedComments', [
                'className' => 'Comments'
            ])
            ->setConditions(['approved' => false])
            ->setProperty('unapproved_comments');
    }
}
```